# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto en ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, asp.net-core

Necesito ayuda por favor, a solucionar este problema que no sé por qué ocurre, ahí dejo imagen de la clase de error

[image: INDEX]

[image: FORMULARIO VISTA]
[image: CLASE FORMULARIO]
[image: CONTROLADOR PRINCIPAL]
[image: VISTA DETALLE]
[image: ERROR OCURRIDO]

Nombre:  
    Carrera:  
    Matricula:  
    Edad:

Comment: La descripción del problema debe ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en el título. Tómate tu tiempo para comentar el problema y el código. Gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Para que podamos ayudarte agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento (no capturas de pantalla). Saludos.

Comment: Toma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykYDale play y pon toda tu atención, te dará un panorama de cómo funciona ASP.net MVC 5

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está en el HTML, utilizas el atributo "name" de manera incorrecta, en cada envío de formularios lo que el servidor espera recibir es lo que lleva dentro de dicho atributo, en este caso, si te fijas bien, estás enviando "Nombre", "Apellido" y "Matricula", el componente "Edad" no tiene atributo "name", por lo que tampoco recibirás la variable.

Toma: [Workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY) dale play y pon toda tu atención, te dará un panorama de cómo funciona ASP.net MVC 5.